# How to setup npm install on machine level?

Tags: npm, angular6, npm-install

Every time I create new app for angular 6, I have to run npm install. This takes a long time. Currently I have checked in my angular app in TFS without node_modules folder so when developers from my team will get latest , they will all have to run npm install to get app up and running.

Is there a better way to structure this ? I can't checkin all the node_modules folder as it will take long time to transfer.

Answer (score 1):

No...there is no other way to do this. Every machine needs to have the packages cached at least once. You could possibly increase your machine's node memory(`max-old-space-size=8192`) so the command runs faster. Also only the first time should take a while, next time onwards should be really fast. I would recommend locking down the versions inside `package.json` so it doesn't try to update everytime. Developers could possibly have different package versions if you don't lock it.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. So if I understand this correctly, every developer every time setup a project or new branch. They have to run npm install before running application. Correct ? Basically if I want to create 3 ng Demo applications, do I need to run npm install 3 times in all those apps ?